# List Column "made by" and "change by" (with presence) not showing the presence

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, person-or-group, presence-indication

I have 2 columns "made by" and "change by" with the following settings: person (with presence).

But it doesn't show the presence.

Like this picture below, it shows I am present by a green square
[image]

But now I made a new list and it doesn't show it anymore.

Who knows the answer?

Comment: Are you checking this in modern experience or classic experience?

Comment: Modern experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint online modern experience, presence is not shown directly in list view.

Presence will be shown on the persona card (with profile picture) when you hover over or click on person name, like:

[image]

Comment: To bad it doesn't work anymore. But thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's a little late.

But you can try this with json formatting.
[image]

Link
https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/person-hover-card